# could we read an object directly into the bytebuffer in java?

Tags: java, bytebuffer

Say I have a `List<Integer> ls`  and I know its length could we allocate length*4 bytes for bytebuffer and use put to directlty read ls into the buffer?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly read ls into the buffer?"

Comment: What have you tried?  Use a loop through the list, get int value and call put().

Comment: When you say 'read' do you mean 'put'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(ls.size()*4);
for (Integer i: ls)
    buffer.putInt(i);
```

One caveat: This function assumes that your list does not contain any **null**-entries.

I don't think you can do much better than this, since the underlying array of `Integer` objects in `ls` is an array of references (pointers) to these `Integer` objects rather than their contained `int`-values. The actual `Integer` objects will reside in memory in some random order, dictated roughly by when they were created. So, it's unlikely that you would find some consecutive block of memory that contains the data that you would need to copy into your `ByteBuffer` (I think this is what you meant by "directly reading" it.). So, something like using [`sun.misc.Unsafe`](http://mishadoff.github.io/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/) will probably not be able to help you here.

Even if you had an `int[]` instead of a `List<Integers>` you probably won't be able to reliably read the data directly from memory into your `ByteBuffer`, since some JVM's on 64-bit machines will align all values on 64-bit address-locations for faster access, which would lead to "gaps" between your `ints`. And then there is the issue of [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), which might differ from platform to platform...

Edit:

Hmmm... I just took a look at the [OpenJDK source-code for the putInt()-function](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/nio/HeapByteBuffer.java#HeapByteBuffer.putInt%28int%29) that this would be calling... It's a horrendous mess of sub-function-calls. If the "sun"-implementation is as "bad", you might be better off to just do the conversion yourself (using shifting and binary-ops) if you're looking for performance... The fastest might be to convert your `Integers` into a `byte[]` and then using [`ByteBuffer.wrap(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap%28byte%5B%5D%29) if you need the answer as a `ByteBuffer`. Let me know if you need code...

Comment: Thanks, I have used a similar method. That is what I am confusing that could I just put the List as a whole into it. Now I realize we could not.